# MD Bootstrap Incompatible with Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, import, require, ruby-on-rails-6, mdbootstrap

I have a Rails 6 app. When it was generated, it put these lines (and others) in application.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

When I installed Bootstrap 4, I added:

```
import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Now I want to add MD Bootstrap. I did a `yarn add mdbootstrap` and added this line to `application.js`:

```
require('mdbootstrap')
```

I get this error in the JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Object.<anonymous> (mdb.min.js:3414)
    at Object../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js (mdb.min.js:3417)
    at n (mdb.min.js:38)
    at Module../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js (mdb.min.js:3297)
    at n (mdb.min.js:38)
    at Object../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js (mdb.min.js:3292)
    at n (mdb.min.js:38)
    at mdb.min.js:74
    at Object.<anonymous> (mdb.min.js:75)
    at Object../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js (mdb.min.js:14068)
(anonymous) @ mdb.min.js:3414
./node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js @ mdb.min.js:3417
n @ mdb.min.js:38
./node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js @ mdb.min.js:3297
n @ mdb.min.js:38
./node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js @ mdb.min.js:3292
n @ mdb.min.js:38
(anonymous) @ mdb.min.js:74
(anonymous) @ mdb.min.js:75
./node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.min.js @ mdb.min.js:14068
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ application.js:31
./app/javascript/packs/application.js @ application.js:177
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
```

**Why does it do this? How can I fix it?**

I read that imports and requires should not be mixed. Does this mean the autogenerated `require` calls should be changed to imports? I was able to convert the requires to imports:

```
import Ujs from '@rails/ujs'
import TurboLinks from 'turbolinks'
import * as ActiveStorage from '@rails/activestorage'
import 'channels'
import 'packs/reports'
import 'datatables.net-bs4'
import 'datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css'
```

Comment: Also, does `mdbootstrap` install `bootstrap` as a dependency, and should I therefore not install `bootstrap` explicitly myself?

Comment: I see now that it is a problem with webpack and ES6 and not specific to Rails: https://github.com/mdbootstrap/bootstrap-material-design/issues/268https://github.com/mdbootstrap/bootstrap-material-design/issues/268. This issue was reported in Dec. 2019 and is still not addressed. There is a workaround at https://mdbootstrap.com/support/jquery/issue-with-4-9-0-webpack-typescript/ but it is Laravel-specific and I am not confident I could translate it to Rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

i got mdbootstrap to work on rails 6, follow this:

add jquery mdb-ui-kit and mdbootstrap to rails:

```
yarn add jquery mdb-ui-kit mdbootstrap
```

on environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
 $: 'jquery',
 jQuery: 'jquery'
}))
module.exports = environment
```

add on javascripts/packs/application.js

```
require("jquery")

import * as mdb from 'mdb-ui-kit';
```

on assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import 'mdb-ui-kit/css/mdb.min.css';
@import 'mdbootstrap/css/mdb.min.css';
```

Comment: Thanks, Jorge. I tried this but was unable to get it to work. Got a JS console error on module build: 

`dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css:7 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 25
    at :3000/shared/work/tepper-bennett/node_modules/mdb-ui-kit/css/mdb.min.css:18`

Also, RubyMine marked `import * as mdb from 'mdb-ui-kit';` as being unused.